# Are there alternate locations for the robots.txt file or configurations that control it?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, robots.txt, iis-8.5

We have a website with a number of applications configured as sub-sites.  Currently none of the sites are being indexed properly by google.  I'm assuming that this is due to the robots.txt file which contains:

`User-Agent: *
Disallow: /`

I can view the robots.txt file by adding the file name to the URL of the root site (example.com/robots.txt) but when searching the actual web server directory there is no robots.txt file.  I have tried to put a new robots.txt file in the root directory but it has no effect.  The only thing that has come up when I've tried to search for this issue is an IIS Search Engine Optimization feature which we do not have installed.  Is there some kind of server setting or policy that is generating the file automatically?  We have access to the web server but it was set up and is controlled by another department.

`VM server
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
IIS 8.5`

Comment: try to remove the disallow rule and analyze the report by using iis Search Engine Optimization. you could find more detail about the feature from this link:[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-search-engine-optimization-toolkit/using-the-iis-search-engine-optimization-toolkit)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Currently we do not have Search Engine Optimization installed.  Are you suggesting we install it?  I am thinking that whatever is creating the robots.txt now would override the SEO toolkit anyway since manually placing a robots.txt file in the proper place is having no effect.

Comment: You could try to use the Search Engine Optimization and check with the report. did you try to remove the Disallow: / ?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Sorry if I wasn't clear in my description but we don't know how to remove the Disallow because we don't know where the robots file is originating from, it does not exist in the root directory.  That is the real nature of the question, to find alternate locations or sources for robots files other than the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that our website is being directed through the Azure AD Application Proxy.  According to this doc web crawler robots are blocked through the aforementioned default robots.txt reply: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-security.